# Localization in asp.net Web Forms on the basis of Time-zone

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

Is there a way to provide Localization in my asp.net Web-Form on the basis of local time-zone of my system ? I want to change the page's Culture (CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture) from the time-zone. I have already implemented this by providing the manual links on the web page as all the websites do...By clicking on Spanish, we find a Spanish UI. What I did is, I generate a page request from that link and get the language from that request and finally set the Culture. as

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if(Request["Language"] != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Request["Language"].ToString());
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Request["Language"].ToString());
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

Now I want to do the same thing with the help of time-zone of the user's system. 
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET has some native support for automatic locale switching via the  web.config section.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="fr" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This setting automatically switches the ASP.NET request to the browser client’s language if a match can be found. If the browser doesn’t provide a language or the language can’t be matched to one of the .NET installed cultures, the fallback value is used – in this case en-US.